# Efficient Image Resizing Algorithm in java

Tags: java, image, image-scaling

I have an image of 3000x3000px I would like to downscale it to 300x300 px, I have used standard Java ImageIo library to do so.

The pseudo code goes something like:

```
Statement1: buffReader = ImageIo.read(new File("bigFile.jpg"));

Statement2: resize(buffread, 300, 300);
```

The problem is the first statement takes 2 seconds! to process.
The Statement 2: takes 78ms to process, which I can live with.

All in all it takes 2.1 seconds, which is unacceptable for downscale of an image, is there a better or faster way to do this ?

On perusal: of Java library of ImageIO.read(), there are two function.

```
ImageIo.read(file) {
    Statement1: BufferedContent content = readFromFile(file);
    Statement2: convertToBufferedImage(content);
}
```

Statement 1: takes around 168ms, which again something I can live with,
but statement 2 takes 1800ms (1.8ms) which I cannot.
I am mentioning this point to prove that I/O is not the most expensive operation here.

Comment: It would seem that your problem is "how do I read an image really fast", and not "how do I downsize it once read". I highly doubt that there is an existing Java package that can do the downsizing while it is reading the data.

Comment: I agree, but if there are any native off the shelf implementation of this would be great too. Which would be non standard ofcourse